# Transaction commit in GCP node js API is returning {"code":10,"rowCounts":[]} with spanner

Tags: sql, node.js, transactions, google-cloud-spanner

I have a API which is written in nodejs for GCP. In the logs sometimes API returns {"code":10,"rowCounts":[]} for first two transactions but all other transaction works fine.

There are no more details in the error other than {"code":10,"rowCounts":[]}.

But if I try to this run this query directly into spanner. The query is getting executed with no errors.

I have the below code for transaction:

```
  database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
    if (queries.length != 0) {         
      try {
        await transaction.batchUpdate(queries);
        transaction.commit(function(err) {
          if (!err) {
            console.log('transaction commited');
        });
      } catch (error) {
        //I get the error here in transaction commit. 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        return callback(some code);
      }
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code samples. There are a couple different ways of running Transactions in the Node.js client, but only the Database#runTransaction method will retry the error you're seeing.

Comment: I have added the sample code. callmehipop, could you please help me out how to retry failed transaction in node js.

Answer (score 2):

The {code: 10} refers to ABORTED [1]. Our client should ideally handle retries on this error code. I filed a bug to track this issue on the nodejs client [3].

In the meantime, you can simply retry the request and it should succeed. There is a guide to retrying the ABORTED transactions here [2]

1. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md
2. https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Spanner.Data/api/Google.Cloud.Spanner.V1.html#retrying-aborted-transactions
3. https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/issues/738

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing callbacks and promises a bit here and if I am reading the code correctly your error actually originates from `batchUpdate`. I'm not sure if this is a side effect of using promises in the callback runner, but could you try running your transaction like this

```
try {
  await database.runTransactionAsync(async transaction => {
    await transaction.batchUpdate(queries);
    return transaction.commit();
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

If you decide to add error handling inside of your `runTransactionAsync` function, it is important to re-throw any ABORTED errors you see otherwise the runner won't know about them and a retry will not be triggered.